# How was "Space Ram" (instant ramen noodles) prepared and eaten on the Space Shuttle?

Tags: space-shuttle, microgravity, food, jaxa

The BBC Witness Podcast [The Invention of Instant Noodles](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/w3cswsfs) mentions that "Space Ram" (ramen noodles for space) was developed for eating on the Space Shuttle. After about `07:00`:

> **BBC:** And at the age of 95, (Momofuku) Ando reinvented the instant noodle once again, this time for a zero-gravity eating experience.
>
> **Tour Guide at the Cup Noodle Museum:** “Space Ram is a type of instant noodle developed especially for space travel.”
>
> **Tsutsui (Nissin foods):** There’s no gravity in space (sic) so first it’s really hard to make ramen in those conditions. And if the soup splashes onto the walls inside the Shuttle, it could cause serious damage because every wall is equipped with delicate, precision instruments. So the soup can never be splashed, and the noodles mustn’t float. He (Ando) developed the technique, and that’s Space Ram.

How was Space Ram safely prepared, and then eaten in zero gravity?

Were there Space Ram prototype tests, or did it just work the first time?

---

Images below are from the BBC web page, but I'm not sure these are what the final product looked like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some brief background on NHK's [Begin Japanology](https://youtu.be/RosUc9UVuos?t=26m46s) Ramen episode.

Comment: @user71659 I love it! Consider adding an answer with the video, or even a screen shot?

Comment: Okay, more importantly, can you get this space ramen anywhere?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like many dehydrated space foods, it's prepared by injecting hot water through a port in an otherwise sealed bag, manually mixing it by massaging the bag, and waiting a few minutes; the noodles are thinner than typical instant noodles so that moderately hot (instead of boiling) water can soften them.

As for eating it without spilling, the secret seems to be thickening it with starch¹. [It was ground-tested prior to going into space](http://www.spacedaily.com/news/food-05j.html), of course:

> [JAXA astronaut Soichi] Noguchi helped test the early stages of the astro ramen, which astronauts can open and eat normally rather than suck through a tube like other space meals.
>
> **The soup is thick enough to prevent spilling**, Nissin said, while the noodle balls retain their shape after being re-heated.
>
> Boiling water is not used in space so Space Ram can be heated with water of 70 degrees Celsius (160 Fahrenheit), thanks to **a unique blend of flour and starch**, it said.

Keep in mind that in zero gravity, reasonably viscous liquids, even water, will stay pretty manageable due to surface tension, [as shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s63JXdsL5LU):

[image]

If a quantity of soup gets away from the package, it will form a tidy drifting sphere and an alert astronaut will have a decent chance at catching it before it drifts into anything expensive.

While food spillage and crumb control are of definite concern aboard the ISS, they seem to rely on sensible amounts of caution and responsible cleanup rather than extreme restrictions on what can be eaten; here's a scrambled-egg breakfast burrito being assembled in zero g, which could be a messy proposition even on Earth.

[image]

¹ Some instant noodle brands use potato starch as a thickener, although not Nissin's "Top Ramen".

Comment: Do you have a video for the zero-g burrito?  That seems like it ought to be interesting.

Comment: @AaronD - Someone else might have the specific scrambled egg burrito video, but here's Col. Chris Hadfield making a [steak, beans, and rice burrito in zero-g](https://youtu.be/f8-UKqGZ_hs), and here's a bit of [scrambled egg getting away from an astronaut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAcyLlGnxK4).

Comment: Ohh, good finds.

Answer (score 11):

If the package on the right of the lower picture in the question was actually flown, it would have been heated in the Shuttle galley's "food warmer" / "oven".  This is because it already contains water and does not need rehydration.

Here is a description from the [Shuttle Crew Operations Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf).

> The oven is divided into two principal compartments:   an   upper   compartment   designed   for    heating  up  to  14  rehydratable 
>   food  containers   inserted  on  tracks,  and  a  lower  compartment 
>   designed  to  accept  up  to  7  flexible  packages.     The  OVEN/RHS
>   ON/OFF
>       switch    provides     power   to   the   oven   heaters   and   the   control    electronics   assembly.   The   oven   fan    ON/OFF
>   switch  enables/disables  power  to  three  oven   fans.  These fans
>   circulate warm air over a heat  sink,  thus  providing  forced 
>   convection  heating   for   the   rehydratable   packages.      The   flexible    packages are held against the heat sink by three 
>   spring-loaded      plates,      and      warmed      by   conduction.    The  oven  has  a  heating  range  of   160°  to  185° 
>   F.    The  oven  door  is  operated  by  a   "squeeze"  latch 
>   requiring  only  3  lb  of  pressure   to open.

[image]

Comment: The article @RusselBorogove linked claims that Noguchi flew it. It may have been for PR more than anything else.  We got close-to-expiration food for the sims, but I never saw this.

Comment: Indeed it does, have read it more slowly now.

Comment: Why does an oven need an aux port?

Comment: It's a hot water outlet. Discussed in the linked document.

Comment: @jab It dates from the 80s so predates MP3s.  That's where they play Space Jam from a 3.5mm lead.